# inline css in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js and material design, can someone help me on how can I make this css as inline css to my md-select tag?

**css:**

```
body md-select-menu, body md-content{
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

here's my **html** code for md-select

```
<md-select ng-model="aaa" name="bbb" required>
    <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
    <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
    <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
    <md-option value="5">5</md-option>
    <md-option value="6">6</md-option>
    <md-option value="7">7</md-option>
    <md-option value="8">8</md-option>
    <md-option value="9">9</md-option>
    <md-option value="10">10</md-option>
    <md-option value="11">11</md-option>
    <md-option value="12">12</md-option>
```

it's now working when I just use the style attribute.

Comment: md-select-menu  in css. your html tag md-select.  which one is correct md-select-menu or md-select

Comment: md-select is the correct one that css is for extending the displayed options in the dropdown field

Answer (score 0):

james,

You won't be able to do it for two reasons:

1. This directive won't map the parameter `style="yourstyle"` to whatever other structure lays underneath
2. You can't apply inline css to nested child elements

I do believe the best way to do it still is having you css class. (This is also pretty good for code reuse)

Comment: check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/bobleujr/pen/PPbvVb) ps. it doesn't work even with !important

Answer (score 0):

```
    <md-select ng-model="aaa" name="bbb" class="mdselectheight" required>
        <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
        <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
        <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
        <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
        <md-option value="5">5</md-option>
        <md-option value="6">6</md-option>
        <md-option value="7">7</md-option>
        <md-option value="8">8</md-option>
        <md-option value="9">9</md-option>
        <md-option value="10">10</md-option>
        <md-option value="11">11</md-option>
        <md-option value="12">12</md-option>
</md-select>

        .mdselectheight{
        max-height: 350px !important;
        }
```

try this i'm not sure this is working or not.